# Where to place Data warehouse

Tags: database, networking, data-warehouse, topology

I am studying networks and I understand that a DW has a structure similar to that in the figure:

[image]

I learned that everything that needs to be accessible outside of your corporate network must be located in the DMZ area:

[image]

If I have several DBs located in different local networks (we suppose a DB in each one of LAN at the bottom of the second figure) and I have to combine them into a DW to standardize the data, where should I position the DW to be accessible to external users on the internet (through the use of a web server, of corse)? Should the DW be in the DMZ? If it is located in the DMZ, how do I connect it to each individual DB distributed among the various local networks of a building (or geographically separate buildings)?

Comment: This is not a programming question and is likely to be closed / migrated.
Generally speaking, you'd only place the front-ends in this DMZ and only allow minimum required access between the frontends in the DMZ and the DW nodes they need to talk to the "marts"?

Comment: where i can place my question?

Comment: Yes, the marts.